# How to store list of workers objects in java?

Tags: java, file, object, serialization

What is the most convenient way to store list of workers in Java considering following conditions:

1. Each worker has attributes of Name, LastName, Wage, BirthDate.
   2.I want to store them in file by appending when needed. For example 1 object I added to file today, 1 tomorrow, 3 in one month and so on.
2. I want to read them also when needed, retrieve, sort, delete, edit and perform other operations.
3. I tried to store them in file with ObjectOutputStream, but the problem is I need to store them at once, so appending later is not possible.

So my question is which type of storing to implement?

Comment: What did you try so far? Where do you struggle?

Comment: Is this a homework question? If so, that's not a problem, but it'd be useful to know because the answer would likely be different to if it were a real-world application.

Comment: I tried to store individual objects into file with ObjectOutputStream with sequential objects appending to file in few  sessions. However, when trying to read them with ObjectInputStream I was able to read only 1st outputed object. I thought if there are some alternative ways to store this data as objects orsome ways to solve ObjectOutputStream appending.

Comment: Its my first real world application I try to make.

Comment: In that case, why the requirement to store them all at once? Surely you want to accommodate the possibility that a new worker will join the company.

Comment: Thats right. I dont want to store them at once. Thats why I search for solution to add a new worker, to append it to those I have added before, and I want to read them all when needed.

Comment: The most robust way to implement this would be to use a relational database to store your workers and to write a program to interact with that database. Have a read about [JDBC](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html).

Comment: Thank you.  Agree about relational database

Answer (score 0):

I suppose workers is a struct...
Have you thought on using an array of workers? or a list?

Comment: Yes. Lets say When I add a first 3 workers to an Arraylist list is written into file. I read workers from file and everything works fine. I close the program. I open it again in 5 minutes to add a new worker, I add it to arraylist and arraylist is written into the same file. When trying to read I receive only 3 first added workers, not the 4th one I added 5 minutes later.

Comment: When you write the list back after adding thzt fourth record, are you _overwriting_ the existing file or _appending_ to it?  You should be  **overwriting**.

Comment: I was maybe appending. Let me try  with overwriting

Comment: exactly, if you rewrite the file content and read it from scratch again it should return the updated version of it

Comment: Also you could use an SQLite database or similar and store the workers there. It might be a little slow reading multiple times from database but if you are not working for mobile device shouldnt be a big issue

Answer (score 0):

So here's the thing I think you're missing: ObjectOutputStream is a method for carrying out serialization (the converting of an object to a writable value). So, to use OOS, you have to implement that in your `worker` class to allow it to be serialized on its own. But, since you want to store more than one of these, you can use one of the many java storage mechanisms (all of which implement serializable).

For this particular situation, I'd recommend using an ArrayList. Put all of the worker objects in an ArrayList and then send that list to the ObjectOutputStream. Then, when you pull the list back into your code from the file, you can continue to add more workers to it as you please and then you can serialize the updated list without a problem.

Once you have the list pulled into your code, you can use `myList.get(index)`, `myList.remove(index)` and all of the other methods that you can find here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

As an aside, I think an ArrayList would be better than a normal array because when you declare and instantiate a normal array you have to specify the length of the array. When you use the ArrayList, you can have as many objects as you want in the list.

Comment: Thanks. Sounds reasonable. I will try to implement it.